# How to get object name in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Is it possible to change value of object ..?

I have this object in Array :

```
Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( 
  [**sdshan**] => 25014408 
  [sduom] => Z5
  [sduorg] => 11651 
 ) 
 [1] => stdClass Object ( 
  [**sdshan**] => 2500880
  [sduom] => Z5 
  [sduorg] => 11193 
 ) 
 [2] => stdClass Object ( 
  [**sdshan**] => 25014447 
  [sduom] => Z5 
  [sduorg] => 5000 
 ) 
 [3] => stdClass Object (
  [**sdshan**] => 2500557 
  [sduom] => Z5 
  [sduorg] => 4200 
 ) 
 [4] => stdClass Object ( 
  [**sdshan**] => 2500348 
  [sduom] => Z5 
  [sduorg] => 4000 
 ) 
)
```

And i want to change the values of **sdshan** into ASDF.
So, the finall Array look like this :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
 [**sdshan**] => ASDF 
 [sduom] => Z5
 [sduorg] => 11651 
) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
 [**sdshan**] => ASDF
 [sduom] => Z5 
 [sduorg] => 11193 
) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
 [**sdshan**] =>ASDF
 [sduom] => Z5 
 [sduorg] => 5000 
) 
[3] => stdClass Object (
 [**sdshan**] => ASDF 
 [sduom] => Z5 
 [sduorg] => 4200 
) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( 
 [**sdshan**] => ASDF 
 [sduom] => Z5 
 [sduorg] => 4000 
)
)
```

Updated, this is what i want try to do :

```
function test(){
    $result = $this->db->select('sdshan,sduom,sduorg')->from('a')->get();
    foreach($result->result() as $data){
       // i want to give some condition here, if sdshan then the values of object sdhsan will be change to ASDF
        $new_result[]=$data; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop array in foreach and overwrite key sdshan by ASDF

Comment: It's possible yes. Can you show us what you've tried ?

Comment: $object.sdshan = "ASDF";

Comment: Good thoughts guys. Also what is the variable name of your array. Or do you have some example code?

Comment: im trying to output data from database by double queries it.
im querying from table A, then 
im querying again from the results to table B.
I just replace the field from result Array B to result Array A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

You can loop through the array and set the value of object by it's key. Like this.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) {
         $object=$array[$i];
         $object->sdshan="your value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
$your_array = array();

foreach ($your_array as $array) {
$pos = array_search($valToReplace, $array );
   if ($pos !== FALSE)
   {
      $array[$pos] = $newVal;
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
foreach(myarray as $key => $myobject){
$myobject->sdshan = "XXXX";
}
```

to use object you have to use -> not .